# In VS Code how to change the JRE for a project only

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

In VS Code I want to run a particular project with an older JRE (Java. 1.8) than the one VS Code and its language server uses (Java 17).

How can I change the JRE for a project to an older JRE? I tried righting click on the JRE in the Java Projects view:

[image: JRE in VS Code]

However, with this I could not get to a related setting.

Comment: Does [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_configure-runtime-for-projects) help?

Answer (score 0):

There are three step in your project.
First you have to download a extension named **Extension Pack for Java**.
Second you have to edit in settings.json of Java.The path is Settings/Users/Java.And add the configuration in it.

```
"java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
            name:"JavaSE-1.8",
            path:"D:\\develop\\jdk\\corretto-1.8.0_362",
            "default": true
        },
        {
            name:"Javase-11",
            path:"D:\\develop\\jdk\\corretto-11.0.19"
        }
    ]
```

Then you must check the jdk version on your maven file or gradle file is the current version you wanted.
The follow is a picture of the operation.The java extension only occure when you installed the Extension Pack for Java

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. Will try it tomorrow when I'm back at the Java machine.

Comment: I have added the runtimes and the default appears now as the runtime of my project, So far so good.  However, is there a way to change the java version that this project uses to a non-default JVM?

Comment: I remember there has some way to change the JDK that Visual Studio used,but VS need to use the JDK 17 and later ,to support some function, you want to change to Jdk 11 is can not be implement. Unless you hope to degrade the VS Version.If you want ,i can told you how to do it...

Comment: Thanks @ash. For the moment I stick with Java-17 for VS Code and Java 1.8 for my (legacy) projects.

Answer (score 0):

> To see which JDKs are used for your projects, you can trigger the command **Java: Configure Java Runtime** in **Command Palette** (`Ctrl+Shift+P`). This command opens a view displaying the runtime information for your projects:
>
> [image]

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_change-jdk-for-unmanaged-folders

The **Java** extension requires a minimum version of **Java 17** to activate the java language server, use the following setting

```json
    "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "E:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-17.0.5",
```

Comment: I do _not_ have the command  **Java: Configure Java Runtime** available. The Java extension is working though, because I have commands like **Java: Export Jar** or **Java: Go to test**.

Comment: This is not possible if you have the full java extension package installed.